# Specific differences between Federated Authentication with SAML compared to OpenID Connect Auth Provider for SSO to SFDC

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I've successfully tested SSO against Azure AD / O365 using the approach illustrated on this [developer.force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login_with_Azure_AD) post, which uses an Auth Provider and the OpenID Connect Provider Type.

However I see a lot of information around Federated Authentication with SAML, and the [Salesforce SSO implementation guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_about.htm) is heavily tilted to SAML.

There is a good bit of information around OpenID connect vs SAML out there on the internet.  I've read posts indicating that openId Connect can do [all that SAML can](http://openid.net/connect/faq/), but is more lightweight and easier to work with, is better for mobile apps, and [is the future](https://apicrazy.com/2014/08/18/why-the-future-of-identity-is-openid-connect-and-not-saml/).

> The Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) is an XML-based federation technology used in some enterprise and academic use cases. OpenID Connect can satisfy these same use cases but with a simpler, JSON/REST based protocol. OpenID Connect was designed to also support native apps and mobile applications, whereas SAML was designed only for Web-based applications. SAML and OpenID Connect will likely coexist for quite some time, with each being deployed in situations where they make sense.

**However, I have not been able to find good coverage in terms of what the Salesforce-specific considerations are.**

I have been focused on OpenID connect, so my knowledge of SAML is limited, but so far what I've found re: SFDC-specific implications is that both are similar in most ways, including

- Both offer just-in-time user provisioning with developer-configurable logic
- Both can update existing user data
- Both let users login using the Active Directory credentials

And they differ in at least one:

- I believe only Federated Authentication with SAML currently allows you to control (force) specific users to authenticate via SSO by permission set.

As I determine what path to take for this project, it would be really helpful to better understand the salesforce-specific implications of these two options that would let me choose one path vs the other.

I have not looked deeply at delegated authentication because it looks like more of a beast, so if there is a compelling reason to look at that as an option for basic SSO against Azure AD i'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: That's an interesting question, I will share my comments as soon as I get some time.

Answer (score -1):

For Salesforce, there are two types of SSO: SAML is Single Sign On, OpenID is Social Sign On:

> With SSO, users can access services without logging in to each one. With social sign-on, users can access a service using their social account credentials.
>
> With social sign-on, users log in to a Salesforce org with their username and password from an external authentication provider, like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, or Google. You can set up any of these providers with a few clicks. With a little bit of work, you can set up other providers, like PayPal and Amazon.
>
> Social sign-on is especially useful when you want customers to be able to log in to a community without having to create (and remember) a new username and password. Customers can log in to a Salesforce community using their Facebook or LinkedIn account.

Single Sign On is authorized by your company, whereas Social Sign On is authorized by another company.

**References**

- [Trailhead: Identity Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/identity_basics/units/identity_basics_product)
- [Differentiating Federated Identities: OpenID Connect, SAML v2.0, and OAuth 2.0 – Software Secured](https://www.softwaresecured.com/differentiating-federated-identities-openid-connect-saml-v2-0-and-oauth-2-0/)